# Remove SharePoint 2010 library authorization using powershell?

Tags: 2010, powershell, document-library, groups, authorization

I know it's possible to modify a library authorizations using the SharePoint UI following the steps bellow:

1. Stop authorizations inheritance.
2. Modify users authorizations.
3. Select/Unselect the desired checkboxes.
4. OK.

I want to add *`Reader`* authorization and remove *`Contributor`*.

How to achieve that using PowerShell?

So far, I succeeded to add new authorizations with PowerShell.
Here is the code.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://www.whatever";         
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"];
$list.BreakRoleInheritance($true,$true);    
$group = $web.Groups["Members of the site"];                
$roleToAdd = "Reader";
$role = $web.RoleDefinitions | where {$_.Type -eq $roleToAdd};                      
$assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group);         
$assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role);          
$list.RoleAssignments.Add($assignment); // How to remove instead ?
$list.Update();     
$web.Dispose();
```

**Note:** I do know that at least one authorization should be selected.

[A solution could be to use this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.roleassignment.importroledefinitionbindings.aspx). Unfortunately it's not working.

```
$roleToLet = "Reader"
$role = $web.RoleDefinitions | where {$_.Type -eq roleToLet };                      
$assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group);         
$list.RoleAssignments[1].ImportRoleDefinitionBindings($assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings);
$list.Update();
```

Answer (score 2):

The list assignments are obtained using the wrong method. Moreover, the assignments were not updated after modifications. Finally I used *`$web.SiteGroups`* instead of *`$web.Groups`*. It should be as following:

```
$group = $web.SiteGroups["Members of the site"];
$rolesToRemove = "Contributor";
$role = $web.RoleDefinitions | where {$_.Type -eq $rolesToRemove};                      
$assignment = list.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal($group);
$assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove($role);
$assignment.update();                                                       
$list.Update();
```